# JS/PHP - получить значение у текущего id

Tags: php, javascript

Добрый день. Есть код:

```
      <?php foreach ($allUsers as $user): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?= $user->login; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $user->email; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $user->sponsor; ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <form action="/admin/delUser" method="post">
                                <input type="hidden" name="deleteUser" value="<?= $user->id?>">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sendEmail" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editUser" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Суть кода здесь идет вывод данных у пользователя в таблице.
Проблема заключается в том, что при клике по кнопке открывается модальное окно и нужно чтобы при клике на нее бралось значение допустим из элемента

```
      <input type="hidden" value="<?= $user->email ?>"
```

И это значение мне нужно получить потом при отправке формы в модальном окне т.е в модальном окне будет форма со скрытым полем и в нее я подставлю уже e-mail пользователя. Вот и возникает вопрос как получить данные при клике на кнопку с поля input , но у текущей строки таблицы! Если сделать получать данные по конкретному id функцией getElementById , то получение данных будет происходить со всех полей у которых есть такой же id. Вот и проблема как получить текущее значение.. увы в js не силен.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариантов достаточно много: продублировать дата атрибуты в кнопки и вытягивать из них информацию, задать уникальный id ячейке   `<tr id="userId">` при клике на кнопу обращаться к ней и искать скрытый инпут, задать hidden инпуту уникальный id, а в кнопках (в дата атрибуте) указывать id скрытого инпута (реализация ниже)...

```js
$('.delete-btn').click(function () {
  var $email = $('#' + $(this).data('hidden-input'));
  $('.modal-body').text($email.val())
  $('#myModal').modal('show')     
})
```

```html
 <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/css/docs.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" classs="email-hidden-inp" id="email1" value="test1@te.te"/>
 <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sendEmail" data-hidden-input="email1" class="btn btn-primary delete-btn"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true">delete1</i></button>
 
 
<input type="hidden"  id="email2" value="test2@te.te"/>
 <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sendEmail" data-hidden-input="email2" class="btn btn-primary delete-btn"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true">delete2</i></button>
 
 
 
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Сделал как у вас , но выходит , что в цикле идет дублирование идентификатора и при клике уже по 2, 5, 7 итд кнопке берутся данные из первого инпута. У вас же написано 2 разные кнопки с разными данными. Конечно можно выставить инкремент и склеивать , но может есть другой хороший способ)))

Comment: Пришлось сделать так . Все работает. Спасибо))

<input type="hidden" id="email<?= $index; ?>" value="<?= $user->email?>">
                                <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-hidden-input="email<?= $index; ?>" data-target="#sendEmail" class="btn btn-primary emailBtn">

Comment: да, правильно сделано